# random sampling 100 times and placing datasets into a list

Tags: r, list, dataframe, random

I have a dataset with multiple ID's that looks like this (shortened version):

```
  ID        Value
  bear 1      1
  bear 1      2
  bear 1      5
  bear 2      2
  bear 2      3
  bear 2      1
  bear 2      1
  bear 2      4
```

I would like to sample one row per ID number and make those rows into a data frame, like this for example:

```
  ID        Value

  bear 1      2
  bear 2      1
```

I then want to this random sampling 100 times, take the resulting 100 datasets and make them elements in a list.

Any thoughts on how to do this? Either using some of the apply()/lapply()/sapply() functions or a loop?

Comment: TRy `library(dplyr); rerun(100, df1 %>% group_by(ID) %>% slice_sample(n = 1))`

Answer (score 2):

We may use `rerun` with `slice_sample`- `rerun` replicates the sampled output `n` times and return a `list`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
n <- 100
rerun(n, df1 %>%
             group_by(ID) %>% 
             slice_sample(n = 1) %>%
             ungroup)
```